# How to get values from variable number of select elements on a form

Tags: php

I have a form that contains a slightly variable number of `select` elements. This is NOT a "multi-select" in which the user can select multiple options, but a variable number of actual drop down menus, each with a single-select value.

The problem is, it is not always known how many of these `select` elements will be on the page. I can give them all a name when I echo them with PHP, but is there a way to gather all of them with `$_POST`? The only way I can think of is to add the names of each `select` element to the `$GLOBALS` array when they are echoed to the page.

Something like:

```
$GLOBALS["selectNames"] = "";
for($i = 0; $i < $number_of_selects; $i++) {
    echo "<select id='select" . $i . "' name='select" . $i . "'>...</select>";
    $GLOBALS["selectNames"] .= "select" . $i;
    if($i < $number_of_selects - 1) {
         $GLOBALS["selectNames"] .= ",";
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Where is the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make them as array and the way you will be able to get all of them using just the name:

```
<select name="s[]">
    <option>v1</option>
</select>

<select name="s[]">
    <option>t1</option>
</select>
```

And in your php code you can access them using `$_POST['s']`, which will be an array that you can loop through.

```
foreach ($_POST['s'] as $key => $val) {
   .... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a fantastic way to do this using the `name` attribute on the `select` element.

#### HTML

In the html, add as many select elements as you want with this format

```
<select name='selects[1]'>
    options
</select>

<select name='selects[2]'>
    options
</select>
```

The numbers `1` and `2` can be left out if you do not need the `$key` variable as noted below.  These values can be anything you want.  Strings are allowed.  Adding the select elements with PHP would look like this.

```
for($i = 0; $i < $number_of_selects; $i++) {
    echo "<select id='select" . $i . "' name='select[]'>...</select>";
}
```

#### PHP

```
foreach ($_POST['selects'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $key;       // This will be the number, so 1 and then 2 ... and so on
    echo $value;     // This will be the value attribute for the option selected
}
```